# Why doesn't MongoDB have transactions? (pre-v4.0)

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Update: MongoDB supports transactions from version 4.0.

Original question:

As far as I know, MongoDB doesn't support transactions, and there are no plans for implementing such support. What is the reason for this?

Comment: There isn't plans? Besides MongoDB is normally designed for non-transactional stuff

Comment: @Sammaye - sure, non-transactional stuff is nice, but having transactions is extremely useful once in a while.

Comment: Wile it could be useful, they generally aren't needed, and I'd rather use MongoDb as it is than suffer the performance impact of supporting distributed multiple document transactions in a sharded deployment.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I suspect I want to hear something like that as an answer :) Why will it give such big performance impact, and why sharded deployment will make it worse?

Comment: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs227/archives/2012/papers/weaker/cidr07p15.pdf

Comment: Closed !? There are facts and not opinions on why MongoDB doens't have transactions like the traditional relational databases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having no transaction is a trade-off to allow MongoDB to be scalable.

The purpose of a transaction is to make sure that the whole database stays consistent while multiple operations take place. But in contrary to most relational databases, MongoDB isn't designed to run on a single host. It is designed to be set up as a cluster of multiple shards where each shard is a replica-sets of multiple servers (optionally at different geographical locations).

A transaction can potentially affect lots of hosts of the database. That means that the transaction would have to be synchronized between all of these hosts. This would mean quite a lot of overhead and would scale very badly when increasing the size of the database by adding more servers.

The [MongoDB FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-do-transactions-and-locking-in-mongodb) explains it like this:

> MongoDB does not have support for traditional locking or complex transactions with rollback. MongoDB aims to be lightweight, fast, and predictable in its performance. This is similar to the MySQL MyISAM autocommit model. By keeping transaction support extremely simple, MongoDB can provide greater performance especially for partitioned or replicated systems with a number of database server processes.